# SESSION y COOKIE no funcionan en subdominios

Tags: php

Tengo un sistema que está en el siguiente directorio: https://site.com. En este directorio el usuario inicia sesión y es redirigido a: https://panel.site.com. El problema es que intenté validar con sesiones, pero no funcionó. Ver:

**Directorio https://site.com**

```
<?php
session_start();
...
if(myqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
  ....
  $_SESSION["Registrado"] = true;
}

Directorio https://panel.site.com

<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["Registrado"] == true)
{
....
} 
?>
```

Como la sesión no funcionó, intenté usar cookies:

**Directorio https://site.com**

```
<?php
...
if(myqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
  ....
  cookie("Registrado",true,time() + 3600);
}
```

**Directorio https://panel.site.com**

```
  <?php
    if($_COOKIE["Registrado"] == true)
    {
    ....
    } 
    ?>
```

El problema es que en el directorio https://site.com tanto la sesión como la cookie funcionan correctamente, pero cuando intento recuperar los valores de ambas en el sudominio https://panel.site.com, me no poder. El subdominio está dentro de /httpdocs.

¿Cómo puedo pasar valores de sesión o cookie de un directorio a un subdominio?

Comment: No es un subdirectorio, es un subdominio, y de ahí que las sesiones se pierdan entre ambos. Es como si fuera un dominio distinto a nivel de sesiones o cookies.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre a bote pronto es controlar las sesiones via una tabla en una base de datos comun entre ambos dominios, y aún así tengo mis dudas. Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Si configura una cookie como esta:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

Entonces la cookie solo se aplicará al dominio de solicitud y solo se enviará para solicitudes al mismo dominio exacto, no a ningún otro subdominio. (Consulte [¿Qué es una cookie solo de host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387338/what-is-a-host-only-cookie) )

Dos dominios diferentes (p. ej . `example.comy` `subdomain.example.com`, o `sub1.example.comy` `sub2.example.com`) solo pueden compartir cookies si el atributo `domain` está presente en el encabezado:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=example.com
```

El atributo de `dominio` debe " coincidir con el dominio " con la URL de la solicitud para que sea válido, lo que básicamente significa que debe ser el dominio de la solicitud o un superdominio. Entonces, esto se aplica a ambos ejemplos en la pregunta, así como al uso compartido entre dos subdominios separados.

Esta `cookie` se enviaría luego para cualquier subdominio `deexample.com` , incluidos los subdominios anidados como `subsub.subdomain.example.com.` (Tenga en cuenta que hay otros atributos que podrían restringir el alcance de la cookie y cuándo el navegador la envía, como path Secure).

Puedes leer el post original [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)   hecho por el usuario @cmbuckley

Dicho esto:

**Para las cookies**

Al momento de llamar a la funcion `setcookie` de php debes pasar como parametro el domino

```
setcookie(
    string $name,
    string $value = "",
    int $expires_or_options = 0,
    string $path = "",
    string $domain = "",
    bool $secure = false,
    bool $httponly = false
)
```

**Para las variables de sesion**

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```